# Scaling Issue On Javascript Banner

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some trouble with a banner section on the homepage and I'm hoping you may be able to help, I can't seem to get it to scale down correctly when viewing on a mobile. The font for the main headline remains the same. Ultimately it would be great to scale the whole banner down including the buttons proportionately.

I've tried various media queries through CSS and have changed the font from pixels to rem & also tried em but the contents of the banner remain the same size. I’m guessing this is down to something in Javascript? Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

```css
<style>
#banner .tp-caption.wbg,
#banner .wbg {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: block;
    height: 350px;
    width: 590px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

#banner .littletext p,
#banner .tp-caption.littletext p {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    line-height: 28px !important;
}
/* Layer 1 */
#banner .version1title h1,
#banner .tp-caption h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 5rem !important;
    line-height: 60px;
    
}
/* Layer 3 */
#banner .version1title1 h1,
#banner .tp-caption h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 5rem !important;
    line-height: 60px;

    
}
/* Layer 2 */
#banner .version1title2 h1,
#banner .tp-caption h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 5rem !important;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    line-height: 1;

    
    
}

#banner .our_service.our_service2 {
    background: none !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;
    border: 1px solid #a4a4a5 !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

.tp-caption hr {
    border-width: 33px;
}

#banner .our_service {
    background-color: #1e2126;
    border-color: #1e2126;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#rev_slider {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#banner h1 {
    line-height: 80px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-size: 6rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

#banner p {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#banner .contact_us,
#banner .our_service {
    width: 155px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#banner .btn-default {
    padding: 12px 20px !important;
}
/**** RESPONSIVE CSS ****/
        @media (max-width: 665px) {
     .banner-wrapper img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .car-details li {
        border: 0 none;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px 0;
        padding: 0 12px;
        width: 32.333% !important;
    }
    .testimonial .lead {
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 26px;
    }
    .search-tab-nav.nav-tabs > li {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 !important;
        border: 0 !important;
    }
    #banner p,
    #banner h1,
    .header-contact {
       scale: 50%;
    }
    .logo-wrapper .navbar-brand {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

@media (max-width:480px){
    .tp-caption.white-small .tp-fade .tp-resizeme.start {
      font-size: 15px !important;
    }
```

```html
<!-- ******************************************
        START SLIDER 
        ********************************************** -->
        <div class="slider-section">
            <div id="banner">
                <div class="rev_slider_wrapper">
                    <!-- START REVOLUTION SLIDER 5.0 auto mode -->
                        <div id="main_slider" class="rev_slider" data-version="5.0">
                            <ul>
                                <li data-index='rs-377' data-transition='curtain-1' data-slotamount='default' data-easein='default' data-easeout='default' data-masterspeed='default' data-thumb='uploads/audi_hero.jpg' data-rotate='0' data-saveperformance='off' data-title='Business Solutions' data-description='' >



                                    <!--************************ MAIN IMAGE 1 INTRO ************************-->
                                    <img src="uploads/audi_hero.jpg"  alt="image"  data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" class="rev-slidebg">
                                    <!-- LAYERS -->
                                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme  " 
                                        data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['-2','0','35','0']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-82','-82','-82','-82']"
                                        data-width="none"
                                        data-height="none"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_in="z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1.5;sY:1.5;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
                                        data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
                                        data-start="1000"
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on" 
                                        data-elementdelay="0.05" 
                                        style="z-index: 5;">
                                        <h1>Unleash Your<br> Vehicles Potential</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme  " 
                                        data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['0','0','35','0']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['22','22','22','22']"
                                        data-width="none"
                                        data-height="none"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_in="z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1.5;sY:1.5;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
                                        data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
                                        data-start="1250"
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on" 
                                        data-elementdelay="0.05" 
                                        style="z-index: 5;">
                                        <img src="uploads/hrslider.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme  " 
                                        data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['0','0','35','0']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['96','96','96','65']" 
                                        data-width="none"
                                        data-height="none"
                                        data-whitespace="nowrap"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2000;e:Power4.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-mask_in="x:0px;y:[100%];" 
                                        data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;" 
                                        data-start="1500" 
                                        data-splitin="none" 
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on" 
                                        style="z-index: 6; white-space: nowrap;">
                                        <p>Our custom road maps are second to none<br> Call us to book, or see your vehicles figures.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme  "
                                        data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['0','0','35','0']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['199','199','199','169']"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:300;e:Power1.easeInOut;"
                                        data-style_hover="c:rgba(0, 154, 238, 1.00);bc:rgba(0, 154, 238, 1.00);cursor:pointer;"
                                        data-transform_in="x:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0deg;rZ:0deg;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="auto:auto;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-start="2500" 
                                        data-splitin="none" 
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on">
                                        <a href="+441370700313" class="contact_us btn btn-default">Contact us</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme  "
                                        data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['193','193','228','193']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['199','199','199','169']"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:300;e:Power1.easeInOut;"
                                        data-style_hover="c:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);bg:rgba(114, 168, 0, 1.00);cursor:pointer;"
                                        data-transform_in="x:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0deg;rZ:0deg;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="auto:auto;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-start="2500" 
                                        data-splitin="none" 
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on">
                                        <a class="btn btn-default our_service js-scroll-trigger" href="#seemyfigures">See My Figures</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li data-index='rs-376' data-transition='curtain-1' data-slotamount='default' data-easein='default' data-easeout='default' data-masterspeed='default' data-thumb='uploads/slider_02.jpg' data-rotate='0' data-saveperformance='off' data-title='Business Solutions' data-description='' >




                                    <!--************************ MAIN IMAGE 2 BECOME A DEALER ************************-->
                                    <img src="uploads/astonmartin_hero.jpg"  alt="image"  data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" class="rev-slidebg">
                                    
                                    <!-- LAYERS -->
                                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                                    <div class="tp-caption" 
                                        data-x="['right','right','right','right']" data-hoffset="['-2','0','35','0']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-82','-82','-82','-82']"
                                        data-width="none"
                                        data-height="none"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_in="z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1.5;sY:1.5;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
                                        data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
                                        data-start="1000"
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on" 
                                        data-elementdelay="0.05" 
                                        style="z-index: 5;">
                                        <h1>Become A Mototech<br>Approved Dealer Today</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme  " 
                                        data-x="['right','right','right','right']" data-hoffset="['0','0','35','0']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['22','22','22','22']"
                                        data-width="none"
                                        data-height="none"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_in="z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1.5;sY:1.5;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
                                        data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
                                        data-start="1250"
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on" 
                                        data-elementdelay="0.05" 
                                        style="z-index: 5;">
                                        <img src="uploads/hrslider1.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme text-right  " 
                                        data-x="['right','right','right','right']" data-hoffset="['0','0','35','0']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['96','96','96','65']" 
                                        data-width="none"
                                        data-height="none"
                                        data-whitespace="nowrap"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2000;e:Power4.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-mask_in="x:0px;y:[100%];" 
                                        data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;" 
                                        data-start="1500" 
                                        data-splitin="none" 
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on" 
                                        style="z-index: 6; white-space: nowrap;">
                                        <p>As a Motortech approved dealer<br> we offer full training & remote support 24/7. </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme  "
                                        data-x="['right','right','right','right']" data-hoffset="['0','0','35','0']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['199','199','199','169']"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:300;e:Power1.easeInOut;"
                                        data-style_hover="c:rgba(0, 154, 238, 1.00);bc:rgba(0, 154, 238, 1.00);cursor:pointer;"
                                        data-transform_in="x:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0deg;rZ:0deg;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="auto:auto;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-start="2500" 
                                        data-splitin="none" 
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on">
                                        <a href="+441370700313" class="contact_us btn btn-default">Contact us</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme  "
                                        data-x="['right','right','right','right']" data-hoffset="['193','193','228','193']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['199','199','199','169']"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:300;e:Power1.easeInOut;"
                                        data-style_hover="c:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);bg:rgba(114, 168, 0, 1.00);cursor:pointer;"
                                        data-transform_in="x:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0deg;rZ:0deg;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="auto:auto;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-start="2500" 
                                        data-splitin="none" 
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on">
                                        <a href="become-a-dealer.html" class="btn btn-default our_service">Apply Here</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li data-index='rs-379' data-transition='curtain-1' data-slotamount='default' data-easein='default' data-easeout='default' data-masterspeed='default' data-thumb='uploads/hero_shifter.jpg' data-rotate='0' data-saveperformance='off' data-title='Business Solutions' data-description='' >




                                    <!--************************ MAIN IMAGE 3 SHIFT MAPS************************-->
                                    <img src="uploads/hero_shifter.jpg"  alt="image"  data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" class="rev-slidebg">
                                    <!-- LAYERS -->
                                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                                    <div class="tp-caption" 
                                        data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['-2','0','35','0']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-92','-92','-92','-92']"
                                        data-width="none"
                                        data-height="none"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_in="z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1.5;sY:1.5;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
                                        data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
                                        data-start="1000"
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on" 
                                        data-elementdelay="0.05" 
                                        style="z-index: 5;">
                                        <h1>Shift Maps<br>Up to 60% <br>faster shift times</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme  " 
                                        data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['0','0','35','0']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['22','22','22','22']"
                                        data-width="none"
                                        data-height="none"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_in="z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1.5;sY:1.5;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
                                        data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
                                        data-start="1250"
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on" 
                                        data-elementdelay="0.05" 
                                        style="z-index: 5;">
                                        <img src="uploads/hrslider.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme tp-fade" 
                                        data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['0','0','35','0']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['96','96','96','65']" 
                                        data-width="none"
                                        data-height="none"
                                        data-whitespace="nowrap"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2000;e:Power4.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-mask_in="x:0px;y:[100%];" 
                                        data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;" 
                                        data-start="1500" 
                                        data-splitin="none" 
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on" 
                                        style="z-index: 6; white-space: nowrap;">
                                        <p>Our shift maps balance the harmony<br> between your ECU & your gearbox</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme  "
                                        data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['0','0','35','0']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['199','199','199','169']"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:300;e:Power1.easeInOut;"
                                        data-style_hover="c:rgba(0, 154, 238, 1.00);bc:rgba(0, 154, 238, 1.00);cursor:pointer;"
                                        data-transform_in="x:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0deg;rZ:0deg;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="auto:auto;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-start="2500" 
                                        data-splitin="none" 
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on">
                                        <a href="+441370700313" class="contact_us btn btn-default">Contact us</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme  "
                                        data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['193','193','228','193']" 
                                        data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['199','199','199','169']"
                                        data-transform_idle="o:1;"
                                        data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:300;e:Power1.easeInOut;"
                                        data-style_hover="c:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);bg:rgba(114, 168, 0, 1.00);cursor:pointer;"
                                        data-transform_in="x:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0deg;rZ:0deg;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-transform_out="auto:auto;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
                                        data-start="2500" 
                                        data-splitin="none" 
                                        data-splitout="none" 
                                        data-responsive_offset="on">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default our_service">More Info</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: can you please add code of that specific this is not helping

Comment: Hi Amin. The code listed is all for the banner? It’s a 3 layered banner that transitions between layers

Comment: If anyone could shed some light on this it would be much appreciated.